# Apache - Displaying files but password protecting them

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a folder on my apache virtualhost called 'ProtectedFiles'

I want indexing available for this section, so all the files in this folder can be shown, but I want one of the files themselves to be password protected.

Folder structure:

- site
- site/ProtectedFiles
- site/ProtectedFiles/Dummy1, Dummy2, Dummy3, .htaccess

In my .htaccess I have the following.

```
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected files"
AuthType Basic
<Files "Dummy1">
require valid-user
</Files>
```

So I am password protecting the file 'Dummy1' and it works, when I go to site/ProtectedFiles/Dummy1 it asks for a password, but the file doesn't show in the directory / index.

[image: Directory]

Basically, asking how do you password protect AND show the file in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **IndexOptions +ShowForbidden** directive to display files that require a password, and the **FilesMatch** directive to indicate which files you want to protect.

```
IndexOptions +ShowForbidden
<FilesMatch "Dummy[0-9]+">
    AuthName "Username and password required"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    AuthType Basic
</FilesMatch>
```

*Don't leave the .htpasswd file in the same directory - this is just an example.*